# How can I Parse a string containing JSX into JSX components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I am currently trying to parse a string that contains JSX into literal JSX,and inject it into the return of my component:

```
import react from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  heading:{
    color: theme.palette.secondary.dark
  },
});

const Foo = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const jsxString = "<span>foo <span className={classes.heading}>bar</span></span>"
  // convert or parse jsxString into literal JSX that can be rendered or returned
  // by the component.
  const jsxReact = ConvertToWhatReactUnderStands(jsxString) 
  return (
    <>
      {jsxReact}
    </>
  ); 
};

export default Foo;
```

I am using `create-react-app`, and I am not intending on **ejecting**.

I have tried the following:

1. `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and this does not work, when inspecting the the element I get:

```
<span>foo <span className="{classes.heading}">bar</span></span>
```

How do I go about achieving this, making sure that my styles are applied?

Also, the inner html `<span/>` tag was a Material-UI `<Typography/>` component, I had to change it because parsing it changed the component name to : `<typography/>` after using the following functions from these packages:

1. `import parse from 'html-react-parser';`
2. `import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';`
3. `import Parser from 'html-react-parser'`

and the following construct `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

I understand that , I would have to transpile/transform the JSX string into javascript  code with something like Babel before I execute it.

For example, when using the browser version of Babel:

```
var jsCode = babel.transform(jsxString);
eval(jsCode.code);
```

But ejecting and using Babel is not an option for me.
To be breif, my question is how would I convert a string into JSX and make sure that my style Classes are are applied? Is it possible without using **babel**?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are trying to do this? I would suggest creating a generic component that renders a different component based on props or something similar.

Comment: So the idea here is to create a section on a web application based on values that are obtained from a database. These values are just strings that contain JSX elements as depicted in the example code.

Comment: Since you do not want to eject and use Babel at runtime, I don't see any other option. But also, IMO i don't think this is the right solution for your problem. Instead of saving JSX in the database, you should be saving some other config/data and based on that render your component. Keep the UI logic out of the backend.

Comment: Thank you @basantSingh, really appreciate your feedback. I believe I will have to somehow find a way for this to work.